ESP32 max partition table size doesn't seem to matter
I'm programming the ESP32 S2 WROOM with PlatformIO with a custom partition table that allows me to store as much data as possible in the app0 partition, and quite a lot of user settings in the nvs partition.
I tried seeing how large I could get the partitions, first I worked by manually calculating the partition offsets, and increasing sizes to humongous numbers like 600MB since the compiler didn't seem to care about the sizes of any of my partitions as long as they stayed within range of a 32-bit number. This is not good since my ESP model should only be allowed to store a max of 4MB, so I tried overflowing the memory offsets, and sizes in different ways to see if the compiler really didn't care... it didn't. This is a problem since I will now never know if the partition table I made is actually valid. This is the latest iteration:
partitions table picture
Also yes, when compiling my code I could see app0 size was increased so it actually reads the table.
In short:
Tried:
Trying to set memory sizes of the different partitions to humongous sizes
Expected result:
Compiler would yell at me for using invalid memory adresses/sizes
What actually happened:
Compiler didn't care

Hi FBM, welcome to SO. Please don't post pictures of text on this site. Just copy-paste the text into your post, surrounded by code tags (```) where appropriate.

Thanks for sharing these guidelines. I will take this into account next time.

The partitioning tools do not know what is the size of the SPI Flash on board your device. That's because the Flash is an external component and can theoretically come in any size sold on the market. Espressif sells devkits with Flash chips in sizes 4-32 MiB. Also, you can install your own Flash chip of any size.
Only when you get around to writing your image into a specific device does it make sense to check if it fits, and the flasher tool does exactly that. Before that, it's your responsibility to do the arithmetic :)

One other question though, now that I've changed a lot in my partitions table when uploading I keep getting this error: Error: Failed to get flash maps (4294967295)! Even with the known working partitions reset. It also doesn't happen all the time, just when for example uploading some other test program but with the same partitions file

Ok I really don't understand partition schemes anymore. I now don't get the "failed to get flash maps" error anymore, but when checking my esp32's serial port it keeps rebooting every time. When using the original partition table it doesn't. I only changed nvs to be a bit larger and removed spiffs:
nvs, data, nvs, 0x9000, 0x15000, otadata, data, ota, 0x1e000, 0x2000, program, app, ota_0, 0x20000, 0x300000, coredump, data, coredump, 0x3F0000, 0x10000,

It seems I am not allowed to change the size of nvs at all, even though I want more then 0x5000 storage, I am also not allowed to change the name of nvs even though this should be allowed according to the official documentation "Name field can be any meaningful name. It is not significant to the ESP32.". These two issues seem to currently be the source of my problems

SOLUTION: found out this post about the nvs resizing problem I have: post I could finally increase nvs size by putting it at the end of the partition table since according to PlatformIO or Ardurino framework app0 will ALWAYS start at 0x10000 which is ******* fantastic. As for changing the name from nvs to something custom, this still doesn't work. Maybe also a PIO or Ardurino bug. The "failed to get flash maps" error popped up because I still uploaded "invalid" partition tables... NOT, which has also been resolved with the fix from the other post
